# collection was modified enumeration operation might not execute while working with datatable and dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I am trying to get a excel file from a certain filepath and merge the dataset with another dataset. Right now i have this. But i keep getting the error:
`collection was modified enumeration operation might not execute`. I was hoping someone could help me. Thanks in advance

```
                    FileStream stream = File.Open("MyFilePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                    DataSet resultReader = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                    excelReader.Close();

                    DataTable excelTable = resultReader.Tables[0];

                    foreach (DataRow dr in excelTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.Table.Rows.Add();
                        excelTable.AcceptChanges();
                    }

                    resultReader.Tables.Add(excelTable);

                    ds.Merge(resultReader);
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row in the table you are adding an additional, empty row to the same table... Why? Because:

```
dr.Table.Rows == excelTable.Rows
```

As the error states, you're updating the thing you're enumerating and you (under almost all circumstances) cannot do that.

Assuming this is what you **really** mean to do (it looks suspicious to me), you can get similar results using a `for` loop:

```
var len = excelTable.Rows.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    excelTable.Rows.Add();
```

Or as the comments point out, you can use `ToList` to create a **copy** that you then *can* enumerate over:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in excelTable.AsEnumerable().ToList()) {
   dr.Table.Rows.Add();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Just the appended part is empty. Do you have any idea what i have to do?